# Текст не выравнивается по середине

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Пробовал всё то, что знаю, но выровнять не получается. Вот код:

```css
.header {
  background-image: url(imag/ph-pc.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
}

.welcome {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="welcome">
    <p>Добро пожаловать</p>
  </div>
  <button class="button" href="pc.html">
    <a href="pc.html">Собрать компьютер</a>
  </button>
</header>
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: `.header {text-align: center;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.header {
  background-image: url(imag/ph-pc.png);
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.welcome {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="welcome">
    <p>Добро пожаловать</p>
  </div>
  <button class="button" href="pc.html">
    <a href="pc.html">Собрать компьютер</a>
  </button>
</header>
```